# From the bash command shell, parsing numbers from a line

Tags: bash

I have a log line that I am pulling from bash like:

```
There are 5 apples and 7 oranges
```

And I want to get the 5 and 7 into bash variables and am having problems doing so.

awk '{ print $3, $6 }' won't work due to the fact that their position might change, if there are bananas. Bonus points if the digits can be associated with their fruits.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about sed? Use a regex and operate on each matche.

Comment: Do you expect exactly 2 occurrences of digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and to get the fruits:

```
echo 'There are 5 apples and 7 oranges' | grep -o -E '[[:digit:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

A bash-only method, tested with bash v4:

```
str=" There are 5 apples, 12 bananas and 7 oranges"

i=0
while [[ "$str" =~ ([0-9]+)" "([a-z]+)(.*) ]] ; do
    num[$i]=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    type[$i]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    str=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    (( i++ ))
done

for (( i=0; i<${#num[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf "%4d\t%s\t%s\n" $i ${num[$i]} ${type[$i]}
done
```

outputs

```
   0    5       apples
   1    12      bananas
   2    7       oranges
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep will do this:

```
echo 'There are 5 apples and 7 oranges' | grep -o -E '[[:digit:]]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more compact version:

`echo 'There are 5 apples and 7 oranges' | egrep -o '[0-9]+ \w+'`

Note however that `\w` is synonymous with `[:alnum:]`, and will thus match "appl3s" as well, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, shell is a strange language, and you can do nice things. For example:

```
a="there are 7 apples"
for i in $a; do
  case $i in
    [0-9]*)
      value=$i
      expectname=1
    ;;
    *)
      test -n "$expectname" && name=$i
      expectname=
    ;;
  esac
done

echo $value
echo $name
```

If you have more than one occurrence, you can fill an array, or a bash map.